# ORA-00979 not a group by expression Error in JPA Query with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am experiencing an issue while trying to create a daily process to generate statistics for my application. I successfully created an initial approach that works for pulling today's statistics:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT " +
               "Arrendador.id AS arrendadorId, " +
               "Tipo_Actividad.id AS tipoComunicacionId, " +
               "TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS fecha, " +
               "COUNT(CASE WHEN TRUNC(Com.fecha_contrato) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN 1 END) AS cantidad, " +
               "NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS fechaUltimoEnvio, " +
               "TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, Arrendador.fecha_alta)) AS diasSinEnviar " +
               "FROM Arrendador " +
               "LEFT JOIN (SELECT arrendador_id, MAX(fecha_contrato) AS ultimaFechaContrato FROM Comunicacion GROUP BY arrendador_id) UltimaComunicacion ON Arrendador.id = UltimaComunicacion.arrendador_id " +
               "LEFT JOIN Comunicacion Com ON Arrendador.id = Com.arrendador_id " +
               "LEFT JOIN Tipo_Comunicacion ON Com.tipo_comunicacion_id = Tipo_Comunicacion.id " +
               "JOIN Tipo_Arrendador ON Arrendador.tipo_arrendador_id = Tipo_Arrendador.id " +
               "JOIN Tipo_Actividad ON Arrendador.tipo_actividad_id = Tipo_Actividad.id " +
               "GROUP BY Arrendador.id, Tipo_Actividad.id, NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')), TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, Arrendador.fecha_alta))",
       nativeQuery = true)
List<EstadisticasProjection> obtenerDatosConsulta();
```

However, the problem arises when I try to obtain statistics for a specific day. I modified the query like this:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT " +
            " Arrendador.id AS arrendadorId, " +
            " Tipo_Actividad.id AS tipoComunicacionId, " +
            " TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:fechaParametro, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS fecha, " +
            " COUNT(CASE WHEN TRUNC(Com.fecha_contrato) = TRUNC(TO_DATE(:fechaParametro, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) THEN 1 END) AS cantidad, " +
            " NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS fechaUltimoEnvio, " +
            " TRUNC(TO_DATE(:fechaParametro, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) - TRUNC(NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, Arrendador.fecha_alta)) AS diasSinEnviar " +
            "FROM Arrendador " +
            "LEFT JOIN (SELECT arrendador_id, MAX(fecha_contrato) AS ultimaFechaContrato FROM Comunicacion GROUP BY arrendador_id) UltimaComunicacion ON Arrendador.id = UltimaComunicacion.arrendador_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN Comunicacion Com ON Arrendador.id = Com.arrendador_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN Tipo_Comunicacion ON Com.tipo_comunicacion_id = Tipo_Comunicacion.id " +
            "JOIN Tipo_Arrendador ON Arrendador.tipo_arrendador_id = Tipo_Arrendador.id " +
            "JOIN Tipo_Actividad ON Arrendador.tipo_actividad_id = Tipo_Actividad.id " +
            "GROUP BY Arrendador.id, " +
            " Tipo_Actividad.id, " +
            " TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:fechaParametro, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), " +
            " NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')), " +
            " TRUNC(TO_DATE(:fechaParametro, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) - TRUNC(NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, Arrendador.fecha_alta))",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<EstadisticasProjection> obtenerDatosConsulta(@Param("fechaParametro") String fechaParametro);
```

The issue is that when executing this select statement, I get the following Oracle error: "ORA-00979 not a group by expression". I have tried passing the date as java.util.Date, java.sql.Date, and as a String, always following the "yyyy-MM-dd" format, but I keep getting the same error. However, when I run the query through SQL Developer, I do not encounter this error:

```
SELECT
    Arrendador.id AS arrendadorId,
    Tipo_Actividad.id AS tipoComunicacionId,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS fecha,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TRUNC(Com.fecha_contrato) = TRUNC(TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) THEN 1 END) AS cantidad,
    NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS fechaUltimoEnvio,
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) - TRUNC(NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, Arrendador.fecha_alta)) AS diasSinEnviar
FROM
    Arrendador
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT arrendador_id, MAX(fecha_contrato) AS ultimaFechaContrato FROM Comunicacion GROUP BY arrendador_id) UltimaComunicacion ON Arrendador.id = UltimaComunicacion.arrendador_id
LEFT JOIN
    Comunicacion Com ON Arrendador.id = Com.arrendador_id
LEFT JOIN
    Tipo_Comunicacion ON Com.tipo_comunicacion_id = Tipo_Comunicacion.id
JOIN
    Tipo_Arrendador ON Arrendador.tipo_arrendador_id = Tipo_Arrendador.id
JOIN
    Tipo_Actividad ON Arrendador.tipo_actividad_id = Tipo_Actividad.id
GROUP BY
    Arrendador.id,
    Tipo_Actividad.id,
    NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')),
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) - TRUNC(NVL(UltimaComunicacion.UltimaFechaContrato, Arrendador.fecha_alta))
```

This last query is copied and pasted directly from the Hibernate log, and this is how I am passing the parameters:

```
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [2023-12-03]
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [2023-12-03]
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [2023-12-03]
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [2023-12-03]
```

I am at a loss for what else to do. The query works fine when executed in SQL Developer, it works for the current day, and it works if I hardcode :fechaParametro to a specific date like '2023-12-04'. I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Need to know how to inyect/pass the date to jpa

Comment: What happens if you include the *missing* `to_char(to_date(:fechaparametro, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')` into the final GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @Littlefoot I got the same error ORA-00979 not a group by expression, I believe the problem lies in how I inject the date. –